# How can I bring my following code to work?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Hi there I am self learner of the 'tkinter' library, my problem is even if I run the following code, I get just white canvas just like in screenshot.

I just want to create a green canvas with a white frame.

```
import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog, Text
    import os
    
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root,height=700,width=700,bg='green')
    canvas.pack()
    
    frame = tk.Frame(root,bg='gray')
    frame.place(relwidth=0.8,relheight=0.8,relx=0.1,rely=0.1)
    
    
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Hi there this the image]

Comment: FWIW, I ran your code and got a dark grey box centered in a green window. (After fixing indentation).

Comment: I agree, this will produce a gray `Frame` on top of your `Canvas` and please fix your indentation.

Comment: I don't understand it why I am still getting just white screen ? Is there any way that you know ?

Comment: Even if I fix it, I still get just white screen

Comment: Are you using macos?

Answer (score -2):

The issue with your code is that you're creating a frame with a gray color, but you're not defining its height and width, which is why it's not showing up in your canvas.

The place() method of tkinter widget is used to organize widgets by placing them in a specific position in the parent widget. However, you're using relative measurements (relwidth, relheight, relx, rely) that don't have an absolute size to be relative to, because the frame's size is not defined.

Comment: This isn’t correct. The relative width and height is relative to the parent of the frame, not the frame itself.